# how to use JUNIT using makefile?

Tags: junit4

I am very new to JUNIT. I have Makefile to compile my code and which will generate a jar file and now I want to run my JUNIT test case for that.

I not sure how to find out `.class` file using JAR. I am using LINUX as I know I need a `.class` file to execute a JUNIT case.

can some one help me?

Comment: Question here is quite old, but still, maybe somebody finds this article useful: http://www.owsiak.org/you-need-no-maven-to-run-junit-tests/

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/you-need-no-maven-to-run-junit-tests/

Answer (score 0):

from http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTestCookbooks:

> I use JavaUnit for my unit tests. For a class Foo, its source is in
>   Foo.java. Its unit test lives in a separate class, with the source in
>   TestFoo.java. A command line invokes the unit test, in either console
>   mode or with a GUI. I use the console mode tester:
>
> ```
> java junit.textui.TestRunner TestFoo
> ```
>
> I build an "all-in-one" test suite for a package, which runs all of
>   the unit tests in the package. It's called TestAll. This is usually
>   the test I run when working on the package.
>
> I add a rule like this to my makefile:
>
> ```
> test: TestAll.class
>     java junit.textui.TestRunner TestAll
> ```
>
> when I run "make test", Test'All.class gets built (through another
>   rule) and then junit is run with the standard command-line.